# How to use JSONSlurper to perform assertion on JSON array response in groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

I'm trying to write extract the name value "Acura" from a JSON array response by using the location of the value stored in a variable called "jsonFieldName".

Below is the code that I'm trying to do this with, however, everytime i run the script, SOAPUI returns error:  "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object error at line: 156"

Can someone kindly advise how to do this?

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response = '''{
"makes": [
{
  "id": 200002038,
  "name": "Acura",
  "niceName": "acura",
  "models": [
    {
      "id": "Acura_ILX",
      "name": "ILX",
      "niceName": "ilx",
      "years": [
        {
          "id": 200471908,
          "year": 2014
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Acura_ILX_Hybrid",
      "name": "ILX Hybrid",
      "niceName": "ilx-hybrid",
      "years": [
        {
          "id": 200493809,
          "year": 2014
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Acura_MDX",
      "name": "MDX",
      "niceName": "mdx",
      "years": [
        {
          "id": 200465929,
          "year": 2014
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Acura_RDX",
      "name": "RDX",
      "niceName": "rdx",
      "years": [
        {
          "id": 200467168,
          "year": 2014
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Acura_RLX",
      "name": "RLX",
      "niceName": "rlx",
      "years": [
        {
          "id": 100539511,
          "year": 2014
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Acura_TL",
      "name": "TL",
      "niceName": "tl",
      "years": [
        {
          "id": 200488448,
          "year": 2014
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Acura_TSX",
      "name": "TSX",
      "niceName": "tsx",
      "years": [
        {
          "id": 200490517,
          "year": 2014
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Acura_TSX_Sport_Wagon",
      "name": "TSX Sport Wagon",
      "niceName": "tsx-sport-wagon",
      "years": [
        {
          "id": 200673755,
          "year": 2014
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 200001769,
  "name": "Aston Martin",
  "niceName": "aston-martin",
  "models": [
    {
      "id": "Aston_Martin_DB9",
      "name": "DB9",
      "niceName": "db9",
      "years": [
        {
          "id": 200473436,
          "year": 2014
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Aston_Martin_Rapide_S",
      "name": "Rapide S",
      "niceName": "rapide-s",
      "years": [
        {
          "id": 200460643,
          "year": 2014
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Aston_Martin_V8_Vantage",
      "name": "V8 Vantage",
      "niceName": "v8-vantage",
      "years": [
        {
          "id": 200472947,
          "year": 2014
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Aston_Martin_Vanquish",
      "name": "Vanquish",
      "niceName": "vanquish",
      "years": [
        {
          "id": 200431313,
          "year": 2014
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
],
"makesCount": 2
}'''

def jsonFieldName = ('makes[0].name')
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText (response)
jsonFieldName.split("\\.").each{json = json[it]}

assert json == 'Acura'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your JSON is good from the response (check by calling `print`) Try adding `.text` to the end of your `jsonSlurper()` Call

It also looks like you have a space between `parseText` and  `(response)`
so it should be

`def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)`

However I would try casting to `ArrayList<LazyMap>` to ensure you can iterate by 
`ArrayList<LazyMap> json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response) as ArrayList<LazyMap>`

Then call :

`json.get('Acura')`

Answer (score 0):

This line of your code doesn't handle the index resolution:

```groovy
jsonFieldName.split("\\.").each{json = json[it]}
```

There is no key with the name `makes[0]`. Instead there is an array of `makes` and you are interested on the first one. The following hardcoded line retrieves the name attribute:

```groovy
def result = json.'makes'[0].'name'
```

As you can see here there is an additional step to resolve the index operator. Of course you can implement this functionality on your own or use [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) instead of `JsonSlurper`.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I managed to get this working by using JsonPath instead of JsonSlurper.

To achieve this I had to import the following:

import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

```
def jsonFieldName = "makes[0].name"
def expectedValue = "Acura"
def jsonSuff = JsonPath.read(response, jsonFieldName)
log.info(jsonSuff)
if (jsonSuff.toString() == expectedValue.toString()){
    log.info("Actual value"+jsonSuff+"is equal to expected value"+expectedValue)
}
```